# В цикле массива перезаписывается переменная, и результатом становиться последнее значение, как решить проблему?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Работаю с fullcalendar на Metronic, в событиях events задаю значения:

```
$('#m_calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    defaultDate: moment(todayDate),

    events: [
        {
            title: productName,
            description: productName,
            start: moment(startDate),
            end: moment(endDate),
            className: "country_0 active"
        }

    ],

    eventRender: function(event, element) {//code}
});
```

в джанговском темплейте есть скрипт с циклом:

```
var activeProducts = [99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];

for (var product = 0; product < activeProducts.length; product++) {
    var id = activeProducts[product];
    console.log(id);

    var productName = eval('productName_'+id);
    console.log(productName);


    var startDate = eval('startDate_'+id);
    console.log(startDate);

    var endDate = eval('endDate_'+id);
    console.log(endDate);
}
```

цикл проходит массив, получаются данные, переводятся Convert string to variable name in JavaScript, и отдаем в events.
Но в результате в календаре выводиться только последнее значение цикла, вместо всех которые есть. В консоли получаю необходимые данные, но в реальности нет почему то. Что сделал не так? Благодарен буду за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: `product <= activeProducts.length;` -> `<`

Comment: "Но в результате в календаре выводиться только последнее значение цикла" - где оно выводится, и что это за "значение цикла"?

Comment: с цикла я получаю переменную productName, ее значение проставил в events в title (название продукта), таких продуктов у меня 7, у них есть соответственно дата начала и дата окончания (время доступности скажем), так вот все эти данные в календаре fullcalendar Metronic и отображаються

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
events: productEvents,
...


productEvents = [];
var activeProducts = [99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];

for (var product = 0; product < activeProducts.length; product++) {
  var id = activeProducts[product];
  var productName = eval('productName_'+id);
  var startDate = eval('startDate_'+id);
  var endDate = eval('endDate_'+id);
  productEvents.push({
    title: productName,
    description: productName,
    start: moment(startDate),
    end: moment(endDate),
    className: "country_0 active"
  });
}
```

Comment: благодарю, все ок, работает!!!

Comment: @sagan Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

В самом объявлении цикла, заместо `var product` Укажите `let product`, let будет создавать каждую итерацию цикла, новую переменную с новым значением, заместо var который в итоге получает последнее значение итерации.

Comment: в консоли да, все ок, но в календарь все равно последнее значение цикла

Comment: Даже если вы указываете let?

Comment: да, сам скрипт отрабатывает правильно, в консоли я вижу необходимые значения, но вот когда я подставляю скажем переменную   productName уже в title календаря, то там это событие отображается один раз, а должно столько сколько есть в массиве продуктов (то есть 7)

Comment: @sagan "сколько есть в массиве продуктов (то есть 7)" - то есть 8?